# What is the fastest way to build a simple publishing site for demo purposes

Tags: 2013, office-365

I want to present for my management the sharePoint 2013 capabilities and for this presentation I want to build a simple publishing site that have an enterprise wiki template inside it using SharePoint 2013.
So what is the more reliable way in my case to do so . Baring in mind that till now we do not have a SharePoint application within our organization. Can I register for free online ?
Br

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get Aaaaahs and Oooooohs from your management is the **SharePoint 2013 Contoso Image**. It's just an image that you can run with Hyper-V. Put in on a nice big machine and you will have **all showcases**.

Answer (score 1):

use sharepoint foundation to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Office 365 Enterprise E3 but limited to 30 days trial [Sign up here](https://portal.microsoftonline.com/Signup/MainSignUp15.aspx?&OfferId=B07A1127-DE83-4a6d-9F85-2C104BDAE8B4&dl=ENTERPRISEPACK1&ali=1)